# How to set all items in a chart to have the same colour in am charts 4

Tags: amcharts

I have a bar chart and i was wondering if there is a way to make all the graphics have the same colour:

https://codepen.io/conormdowney/pen/xmVRjd

```
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
```

````
chart.data = [{
  "category": "Research",
  "value1": 450,
  "value2": 1200,
  "value3": 960,
  "value4": 710,
  "value5": 900
}, {
  "category": "Marketing",
  "value1": 1200,
  "value2": 450,
  "value3": 850,
  "value4": 1250,
  "value5": 950
}, {
  "category": "Distribution",
  "value1": 1850,
  "value2": 1700,
  "value3": 450,
  "value4": 870,
  "value5": 600
}];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
//categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
function createSeries(field) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
  return series;
}

createSeries("value1");
createSeries("value2");
createSeries("value3");
createSeries("value4");
createSeries("value5");```
````

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods:

1. The obvious method is to manually set each series color to be the same. You can pull from the chart's color list too, if you prefer, e.g.

```
  series.columns.template.fill = chart.colors.getIndex(0);
  series.columns.template.stroke = chart.colors.getIndex(0);
```

2. Alternatively, you can set [`reuse`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/colorset/#reuse_property) to true on the chart's `colors` object to have it only reuse colors from the list. Setting the list to a single color will essentially be the same as the lines from the first method:

```
chart.colors.reuse = true;
chart.colors.list = [
  am4core.color("#845EC2")
];
```

Answer (score 0):

As @xorsparks answer, but my bars were a variation of my one colour. I found that I had to set `chart.colors.passOptions = {};` to stop that from happening.